# Vagrant outputs loads of Ruby warnings

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-20.04

`vagrant` outputs warnings like these:

```
NOTE: Gem::Specification.default_specifications_dir is deprecated; use Gem.default_specifications_dir instead. It will be removed on or after 2020-02-01.
Gem::Specification.default_specifications_dir called from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:428.
NOTE: Gem::Specification.default_specifications_dir is deprecated; use Gem.default_specifications_dir instead. It will be removed on or after 2020-02-01.
Gem::Specification.default_specifications_dir called from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb:428.
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:354: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:92: warning: The called method `add_config' is defined here
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/errors.rb:103: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/i18n-1.8.2/lib/i18n.rb:195: warning: The called method `t' is defined here
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/ui.rb:171: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/ui.rb:223: warning: The called method `say' is defined here
```

They seem to be internal `vagrant` warnings and not about my use of `vagrant`.

The amount of warnings is around 10x the output of `vagrant` itself. This makes it harder to see the output from `vagrant`.

Is there a way I can get rid of those?

Comment: are you running in debug mode ?

Comment: Nope. Just pure Vagrant from the official Ubuntu 20.04 repository.

Answer (score 0):

I removed ubuntu repo version (2.2.6) and using latest vagrant version (i.e. 2.2.9) solved the issue